# MVC HTML Editor

Tags: html, model-view-controller, editor

Can you recommend an WYSIWYG HTML Editor that works well with ASP.NET MVC? Any experience of the retail version of Obout's HTML Editor?

Answer (score 7):

I use [tinymce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/).  Its a javascript wysiwyg.  It will turn any textarea into a wysiwyg with a simple init script

It will write great xhtml and plugins are easy to add or download and it will work with mvc or whatever technology is used so long as it renders html

Comment: Yes simply add a location to a stylesheet in the init function.  the docs are pretty good